# Grails pogo method calls within a transaction

Tags: grails

This may be a dumb question.

I'm on a time constraint so I don't have much time to play with it, but if I call a pogo object's method residing in src/groovy from a grails service and it performs JDBC database work, will all of it be included within the current transaction? Or should I make these pogos into services?

Can't find the answer directly anywhere and don't have much time to experiment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you're within a transaction, any GORM methods you call (directly or indirectly) from there will execute within that transaction unless the code makes a special effort to do something different (e.g. using its own `withTransaction {}` block).

Comment: I won't actually be calling any GORM methods. From the service I will be calling a normal groovy object's method from the src/groovy package to do some database work (it is making JDBC template calls to a database that we aren't using GORM with). I just want to make sure that the operations within a groovy object that isn't a domain or service will be covered by its caller's transaction.